# How to tell CSS to 'use next most specific rule to determine this property'

Tags: css, material-ui, jss

I'm using Material-UI and JSS to manage my CSS, and I've run into an issue where the styles differ between development and production.

The reason this appears to be - is that the order of the rules in file must be different.

ie. for an element `<div class = "foo bar"/>` in development the stylesheet looks like :

```
.foo {
    color: red; 
}

.bar {
    color: blue; 
}
```

while in production it will look like:

```
.bar {
    color: blue; 
}

.foo {
    color: red; 
}
```

causing them to look different.

What I'm wondering is if for the `.bar` rule I can apply something like `color: unset`, to tell CSS - 'Ignore me, let any other rules set this'.

```css
.bar {
  color: blue; 
}

.foo {
  color: red; 
}

p.foo {
  /*do what here?  I want the color to be blue, without explicitly setting it this way*/
}
```

```html
<p class = "foo bar">
   hello world!
</p>
```

Comment: Your examples are kind of confusing. In the first section you have `.bar` setting the color to blue but want it to be overridden. But in the second section you have `.bar` setting the color to green and want `.foo` to be overridden. Can you change the examples to be consistent so it's clearer what you want the outcome to be?

Comment: @ScottSchupbach - Sorry- sure thing done.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want `.bar` elements to have color blue and `.foo` elements to have color red, but when both are used, you want the color to be blue. If so, you just need to make the `.bar` rule more specific than the `.foo` rule. You could do this in a number of ways.

One would be to create a rule that explicitly covers the case where both classes are used simultaneously. This will ensure that the correct color is always used in those cases:

```css
.foo.bar { 
  color: blue;
}
```

Alternately, you could identify the specific tags that `.bar` can appear on and create rules for each case. This will give those rules higher specificity and they will win out over the less specific `.foo` rule:

```css
div.bar,
p.bar, 
h1.bar {
  color: green;
}
```

Also, in case CSS specificity is an unfamiliar concept, [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) have good explanations.